# how to type math equation direct in tkinter python by keyboard shorcuts

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, sympy

The following code is written in two fields. How do I change the code so that we can write the mathematical formulas directly in the input field of the Python text? like this : https://simpleclub.github.io/math_keyboard/

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
try:
 import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
 import tkinter as tk

def graph(event=None):
 tmptext = entry.get()
 tmptext = "$"+tmptext+"$"

 ax.clear()
 ax.text(0.2, 0.6, tmptext, fontsize=50)  
 canvas.draw()
root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(mainframe, width=70)
entry.pack()
label = tk.Label(mainframe)
label.pack()
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=label)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
entry.insert(0, r"\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \frac{y_i}{z_i}")
graph()
root.bind("<Return>", graph)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want to write formulas or to use keyboard shortcuts?  Tkinter has no method to write formulas like on your link. If you want to use keyboard to put some longer text then use `bind()`.

Comment: I do not want to make software like the link above, I just want to write mathematical formulas very simply with the keyboard, but directly

Comment: You mean Python does not have such a capability ???
So should I go to another programming language ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean `tkinter` doesn't have widget with this capability, not `Python`. But still it would be complex task to do it in `tkinter`. You could try to use widget which can display `HTML` and use `JavaScript` to do this but standard `tkinter` widget can't run `JavaScript` and it would need to use external module like `CEF` - `Chrome Embeding Framework`. Maybe if you would use `PyQt` instead of `tkinter` then you could use its standard widget `WebKit` which can run JavaScript (and it was used to build old browsers `Safari` and `Chrome`).

Comment: Frankly, it would be complex task in any language. If there is no special module in some language (or rather in GUI framework) then you would have to write all code from scratch - and this can be big problem.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information, I'm trying with pyqt and javascript. I hope I finally get the result.
Thanks again dear master.

Comment: Since you are already trying with `JavaScript` may I suggest that you take a look around `pywebview`. It is a _`lightweight cross-platform wrapper around a webview component that allows to display HTML content in its own native GUI window. ... It gives you power of web technologies in your desktop application, hiding the fact that GUI is browser based.`_ - https://pywebview.flowrl.com/